# rendering a table using $http angular

Tags: angularjs

what I'm I doing wrong here? I'm trying to render a table using angular but the table shows empty, with `{{ place.id}}` , `{{ place.name}}` and `{{ place.social}}` where the data should be.

```
 <head>  
   <title>Angular JS </title>  

   <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>  
   <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-resource.js"></script>  
   <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

   <script>
      var app = angular.module('MyForm', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource']);  
      app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) { 
        $http.get('http://passarola.pt/api/places').success(function(data) {
        $scope.predicate = 'id';  
        $scope.reverse = true;  
        $scope.currentPage = 1; 
      };

      $scope.order = function (predicate) {  
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;  
        $scope.predicate = predicate;  
      };  

     $scope.totalItems = $scope.places.length;  
     $scope.numPerPage = 5;  
     $scope.paginate = function (value) {  
       var begin, end, index;  
       begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;  
       end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;  
       index = $scope.places.indexOf(value);  
       return (begin <= index && index < end);  
     };  
   }); 
   </script>

 </head>  

 <body ng-app="MyForm">  
   <div ng-controller="myCtrl">  
     <div class="container-fluid">  
       <pre>Passarola Beer</pre>  
       <hr />  
       <table class="table table-striped">  
         <thead>  
           <tr>  
             <th class="media_gone">  
               <a href="" ng-click="order('id')">ID</a>  
             </th>  
             <th><a href="" ng-click="order('name')"> Name</a> </th>  
             <th><a href="" ng-click="order('social')">Social Media</a> </th>  
           </tr>  
         </thead>  
         <tbody>  
           <tr>    
             <td class="media_gone2"> <input type="text" ng-model="search.id" /></td>  
             <td> <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" /> </td>    
           </tr>  
           <tr ng-repeat="place in places | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:paginate| filter:search" ng-class-odd="'odd'">    
             <td>{{ place.id}}</td>  
             <td>{{ place.name}}</td>  
             <td class="gender_gone">{{ place.social}}</td>  
           </tr>  
         </tbody>  
       </table>  
       <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"  
             max-size="5" boundary-links="true"  
             items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">  
       </pagination>  
     </div>  
   </div>  
 </body>  
 </html>
```

Example code:

```
var app = angular.module('MyForm', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource']);  
   app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {  
     $scope.predicate = 'id';  
     $scope.reverse = true;  
     $scope.currentPage = 1;  
     $scope.order = function (predicate) {  
       $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;  
       $scope.predicate = predicate;  
     };  
     $scope.places = [  
       { id: 'Kevin', name: 25, social: 'boy' },  
       { id: 'John', name: 30, social: 'girl' },  
       { id: 'Laura', name: 28, social: 'girl' },  
       { id: 'Joy', name: 15, social: 'girl' },  
       { id: 'Mary', name: 28, social: 'girl' },  
       { id: 'Peter', name: 95, social: 'boy' },  
       { id: 'Bob', name: 50, social: 'boy' },  
       { id: 'Erika', name: 27, social: 'girl' },  
       { id: 'Patrick', name: 40, social: 'boy' },  
       { id: 'Tery', name: 60, social: 'girl' }  
     ];  
     $scope.totalItems = $scope.places.length;  
     $scope.numPerPage = 5;  
     $scope.paginate = function (value) {  
       var begin, end, index;  
       begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;  
       end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;  
       index = $scope.places.indexOf(value);  
       return (begin <= index && index < end);  
     };
```

Comment: check the browser console for errors.  whenever you see the raw expressions with `{{ }}` rather than just blank space or your data, that is a strong indication that angular failed to load for some reason.

Comment: @Claies it says `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` and `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyForm due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'MyForm' is not available!`

Comment: OK, I solved that part, but now it says `Error: $scope.places is undefined` and I don't know what to do

Comment: You didnt define $scope.places anywhere in your controller

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli would you explain me how to do it?

Comment: In your code that you have posted , u are accessing the length of $scope.places without defining it . Thats why u are getting that error. Where are u assigning the data to $scope.places in your code

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli I used the code from an example and sitched the names, but I'm not quite sure what I'm doing... but in that example I also had this     ` $scope.places = [  
       { id: 'Kevin', name: 25, social: 'boy' },  
       { id: 'John', name: 30, social: 'girl' },  
       { id: 'Laura', name: 28, social: 'girl' },  
       { id: 'Joy', name: 15, social: 'girl' },  
       { id: 'Mary', name: 28, social: 'girl' },  
       { id: 'Peter', name: 95, social: 'boy' },  
     ];  `

Comment: Please post your entire controller code in the example

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli but I can't make the list myself, I have this link `http://passarola.pt/api/places` to get the data from

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli It's there in the EDIT

Comment: CHeck your console for errors , your code looks fine

Comment: Is this your entire js code ?

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli just to make it clear, the first code I posted, is my current entire code that gives me `Error: $scope.places is undefined`; the example code is the code from a tutorial I saw online and it works fine

Comment: @Ujjwalkaushik yes, except for the css

Comment: For using array variables inside ur controller it is a mandatory that u need to declare and tell angular that it is an array in your case **$scope.places= [ ];* . Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I don't see any closing for your controller , you are missing }); I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this controller code.

```
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.places = [];
    $http.get('http://passarola.pt/api/places').success(function(data) {
       $scope.places = data.data;
       $scope.totalItems = $scope.places.length;
       $scope.predicate = 'id';  
       $scope.reverse = true;  
       $scope.currentPage = 1; 
  };

  $scope.order = function (predicate) {  
    $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;  
    $scope.predicate = predicate;  
  };    
 $scope.numPerPage = 5;  
 $scope.paginate = function (value) {  
   var begin, end, index;  
   begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;  
   end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;  
   index = $scope.places.indexOf(value);  
   return (begin <= index && index < end);  
 };  
});
```

Comment: just for knowledge purpose can u guys post a working demo of this code ? Thanks !